# Creating a flag with same subject,same category,same location and with different visits in sas

Tags: sas

1.Same Subject,Category,subcategory,location and same severity for subject 20 and 90 then i need to flag as "N"  2.if same any of the above mentioned key variables are not same then Y, if only one visit is there then also Y....

```
data want;
input Subject category $ subcategory $ loc $ visitnum severity $ wanted_flag $;
datalines;
100 UAE Dubai Sharja 90 MILD N

100 UAE Dubai Sharja 20 MILD N

101 UAE Dubai Abudabi 90 MILD Y

101 UAE Dubai Abudabi 20 MODERATE Y

102 UAE Dubai AlAin 20 MODERATE Y

102 UAE Dubai Kuwait 20 MODERATE Y

102 IND MUMBAI Delhi 20 MILD Y

103 IND Chennai Kolkata 90 MODERATE N

103 IND Chennai Kolkata 20 MODERATE N
104 US  NY      Huston  20 MILD    Y
;
run;
```

The below is the sample information i have and the needed flag is also mentioned as Wanted_flag.

```
Subject category  subcategory   location   visitnum   severity   wanted_flag
100        UAE        Dubai       Sharja      90        MILD        N
100        UAE        Dubai       Sharja      20        MILD        N
101        UAE        Dubai      Abudabi      90        MILD        Y
101        UAE        Dubai      Abudabi      20       MODERATE     Y
102        UAE        Dubai       Al Ain      20       MODERATE     Y
102        UAE        Dubai       Kuwait      20       MODERATE     Y
102        IND        MUMBAI       Delhi      20        MILD        Y
103        IND        Chennai    Kolkata      90       MODERATE     N
103        IND        Chennai    Kolkata      20       MODERATE     N
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and format your data to ensure that its read in correctly or provide it as a data step.

Comment: i have formatted the data as mentioned and added a data step as well

Comment: What indicates a different 'visit', different severity or a combination of other variables? Your first two records have the same subject, category, & location but different visitnum but are not marked as different?

Comment: And why is the last 102 marked as Y, when it isn't the same location?

Comment: my requirement is if one subject with  category, & location  in the first visit and if severity same for next visit also i want to eliminate it ... but since we have different cases like above data the code should be dynamic to accommodate all cases

Comment: And why is the last 102 marked as Y, when it isn't the same location?-- Yes

Comment: I'm sorry the logic for flagging is still unclear to me.

Comment: 1.Same Subject,Category,subcategory,location and same severity for subject 20 and 90 then i need to flag as "N"  2.if same any of the above mentioned key variables are not same then Y, if only one visit is there then also Y....

Comment: Please add your requirements to your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248762/discussion-between-manesh-and-reeza).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've posted this creates the desired results.

```
data have;
input Subject category $ subcategory $ loc $ visitnum severity $ wanted_flag $;
datalines;
100 UAE Dubai Sharja 90 MILD N
100 UAE Dubai Sharja 20 MILD N
101 UAE Dubai Abudabi 90 MILD Y
101 UAE Dubai Abudabi 20 MODERATE Y
102 UAE Dubai AlAin 20 MODERATE Y
102 UAE Dubai Kuwait 20 MODERATE Y
102 IND MUMBAI Delhi 20 MILD Y
103 IND Chennai Kolkata 90 MODERATE N
103 IND Chennai Kolkata 20 MODERATE N
104 US  NY      Huston  20 MILD    Y
;
run;

data want;
set have;
by subject category subcategory loc severity notsorted;
if not (first.severity and last.severity) then flag='N';
else flag='Y';
run;
```